# How to use $(this) selector to animate divs with the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have two divs, with the same class name of `.pageSlide`. When I click on the button with class name `.moveup` or `.movedown`, I specifically want that button's respective  div to slide up or down. At the moment, if I click on the button associated with say, div A, then div B also animates. I'm guessing I need a $(this) selector in the JS somewhere. I'm not sure.

Here's a jsfiddle of working code
https://jsfiddle.net/hpe459ok/

Essentially I have this:

```js
$('.moveup').click(function() {
  if ($('.pageSlide').css('top') == '-420px') {
    $('.pageSlide').animate({
      top: '0'
    }, 700);
  } else {
    $('.pageSlide').animate({
      top: '0'
    }, 700);
  }
});

$('.movedown').click(function() {
  if ($('.pageSlide').css('top') == '0') {
    $('.pageSlide').animate({
      top: '420'
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('.pageSlide').animate({
      top: '420'
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="page1">
    content
    <button class="moveup">Next page</button>
  </div>
  <div class="page2 pageSlide">
    content
    <button class="movedown">Previous page</button>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="page1">
    content
    <button class="moveup">Next page</button>
  </div>
  <div class="page2 pageSlide">
    content
    <button class="movedown">Previous page</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You've unique parent divs i.e. `.container1` and `.container2`, why not use these to listen for events?

Comment: Both of your `div` elements use the `pageSlide` class and it is that class that you are animating. If you give each of them different classes, it will work.

Comment: Please take a step back and think "DRY".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code:

```
$('.moveup').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".page1").siblings('.pageSlide').animate({
      top: '0'
    }, 700);
});

$('.movedown').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".page2").animate({
      top: '420'
    }, 500); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on your `.moveup` and `.movedown` buttons. By setting an attribute `data-parent` to be the id of the top level parent `<div>` it becomes trivial to modify your existing functions to handle the proper animations.

```js
$('.moveup').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).data('parent');
  
  if ($('#'+parent).find('.pageSlide').css('top') == '-420px') {
    $('#'+parent).find('.pageSlide').animate({
      top: '0'
    }, 700);
  } else {
    $('#'+parent).find('.pageSlide').animate({
      top: '0'
    }, 700);
  }
});

$('.movedown').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).data('parent');
  
  if ($('#'+parent).find('.pageSlide').css('top') == '0') {
    $('#'+parent).find('.pageSlide').animate({
      top: '420'
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('#'+parent).find('.pageSlide').animate({
      top: '420'
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
  .pageSlide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 400px;
  background: ghostwhite;
  z-index: 0;
}

.page2 {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 420px;
}

.image-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: black 1px solid;
}

.overlay-left {
  background-color: white;
}

.overlay-right {
  background-color: white;
}

.image-overlay-content-left {
  background-color: white;
}

.image-overlay-content-right {
  background-color: white
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small-12 columns" id="nominate">

  <div class="image-wrapper overlay overlay-left">
    <div class="image-overlay-content image-overlay-content-left" id="formslide">
      <form id="foo" method="post" name="nomForm" action="nominate-test.html#thankyou">

        <div class="page1">
          <label class="row">
            <h2 class="headline">Your name</h2>
            <input placeholder="e.g. John Smith" type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" autofocus>
            <span id="nameError" class="error headline"></span>
          </label>

          <label class="row email">
            <h2 class="headline">Your email address</h2>
            <input placeholder="example@rofordaward.co.uk" type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="2">
            <span id="emailError" class="error headline"></span>
          </label>

          <label class="row">
            <h2 class="headline">Company name</h2>
            <input placeholder="e.g. Roford" type="text" name="company" id="company" tabindex="3">
            <span id="companyError" class="error headline"></span>
          </label>
          <div class="next">
            <button type="button" class="moveup" data-parent="nominate">Next page</button><i class="icon-down-open"></i></div>
        </div>

        <div class="pageSlide page2">
          <label class="row reason">
            <h2 class="headline">Reason for nomination</h2>
            <textarea id="textarea" rows="6" cols="25" maxlength="1000" name="message" id="message" placeholder="A brief evidence based summary"></textarea>
            <span id="messageError" class="error headline"></span>
            <div id="text-area-wrap">
              <div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
            </div>
          </label>

          <div class="row button-wrap">
            <div class="column small-12">
              <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="prev">
            <button type="button" class="movedown" data-parent="nominate">Previous page</button><i class="icon-up-open"></i></div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="small-12 columns" id="apply">

  <div class="image-wrapper overlay overlay-right">

    <div class="overlay-option-headline overlay-option-headline-right">
      <h5>Tell us why you're a great business</h5>
      <h1 class="headline">Apply</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="image-overlay-content image-overlay-content-right">
      <div class="page1">
        <h2 class="headline">Application Form</h2>

        <div class="row apply-points">
          <div class="column small-12">
            <h5>Please make sure you have read our <a href="about.html">Criteria</a> page and <a href="#">terms and conditions</a> in full before applying.</h5></div>

          <div class="column small-12">
            <h5>Ensure you have gathered evidence to support your application.</h5></div>

          <div class="column small-12">
            <h5>Shortlisted companies will be contacted with further instructions.</h5></div>
        </div>
        <div class="next">
          <button type="button" class="moveup" data-parent="apply">Next page</button><i class="icon-down-open"></i></div>
      </div>

      <div class="page2 pageSlide">
        <h2 class="headline">Contact name</h2>

        <div class="row apply-points">
          <div class="column small-12">
            <h5>aduhwijdaduhwijdaduhwijd aduhwijd aduhwijd aduhwijd aduhwijd aduhwijd aduhwijd aduhwijd aduhwijdaduhwijdaduhwijdaduhwijdaduhwijdad aduhwijd aduhwijd aduhwijdaduhwijd aduhwijd ijdaduhwijdaduhwijdaduhwijdaduhwijdad aduhwijd aduhwijd aduhwijdaduhwijd aduhwijd</h5></div>
        </div>
        <div class="prev">
          <button type="button" class="movedown" data-parent="apply">Previous page</button><i class="icon-up-open"></i></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```